# questions about the michael line

Tags: general-topology

this is what i have for a definition: Let $X= \mathbb{R} $ and $ \tau_M=\{U \cup F : U $ is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R} $ and $ F \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} $. This is called the Michael line denoted by $M$

I think I understand the basic idea but I'm not sure. if i take $x=(2,3) \cup \{\pi,\sqrt{2}\}$, $y=(3,5) \cup \{\pi,\sqrt{2}\}$, $z=(2,3) \cup \{e,\sqrt{3}\}$  are those open sets on the micheal line? are they called points on the micheal line or open sets on the micheal line? should they be $x=(2,3) \cup \{\{\pi\},\{\sqrt{2}\}\}$ instead?

Comment: Looks to me like you're taking ordinary open sets and sprinkling in any irrationals you want. Interesting.

Comment: That's kinda what it looks like to me too, but I'm not totally sure if that is what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying set of the Michael line is $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, and the real numbers would be the *points* of the Michael line.

The *open sets* are all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $U \cup F$ where $U$ is open in the usual (metric/order) topology, and $F \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

So in your question, each of $x,y,z$ are open subsets of the Michael line.

However $(2,3) \cup \{ \{ \pi \} , \{ \sqrt 2 \} \}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (so it cannot be an open set in the Michael line).

Comment: I don't understand that last part. $(2,3) \cup \{ \{ \pi \} , \{ \sqrt 2 \} \}$ isn't open in $\mathbb{R}$ because $\{\{ \pi \} , \{ \sqrt 2 \} \}$ isn't open because $\{ \pi \}$ isn't open and $\{ \sqrt 2 \}$ isn't open in $\mathbb{R}$ correct? But $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are each open subsets of $F \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ so wouldn't that still work because it is of the form $U \cup F$ since $(a,b)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{ \{ \pi \} , \{ \sqrt 2 \} \} \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$? Is it because $\{\{\pi\},\{\sqrt2\}\}$ is a set of sets?

Comment: @chris: $\{ \{ \pi \} , \{ \sqrt{2} \} \}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; it is a subset of $\mathcal{P} ( \mathbb{R} )$.  In order to be open in the Michael line, a set must first of all be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.